# How to create a simple editable dataGrid in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, editing

I want to bind an 'ObservableCollection' to a Silverlight dataGrid and allow the contents to be editable.

I've got the following XAML, which allows the editing in the UI, but once I click off the row it changes back to the original.

I'm obviously missing something, any ideas?

```
    <sdk:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  Height="81"
                  Margin="520,349,60,0"
                  Name="MessageBoxButtons"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ButtonsView}"
                  AlternatingRowBackground="Gainsboro"
                  RowBackground="White"
                  HeadersVisibility="All"
                  BorderThickness="2"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  CanUserSortColumns="False">                      
        <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
            <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding}"
                                    CanUserReorder="True"
                                    CanUserResize="True"
                                    CanUserSort="True"
                                    Width="*"
                                    Header="Button Text" />               
        </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
    </sdk:DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Strings are immutable.** That is, you cannot change the value of a specific instance of a string. What happens when you assign string values to strings is that a new String object is created and assigned to your variable.

Binding normally works on properties of objects. You are basically treating the string as both a source of data and a property that can be changed. The end result is that the value is changed then thrown away as the actual strings in the list are not replaced.

*You want to have a list of simple objects that have string properties instead.*